# 'import futures' does not work even though it is certainly installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, concurrent.futures

I am trying to work on parallelization in python 2.7, and have certainly installed `futures` package. When I try `import futures`, it gives me an error `ImportError: No module named futures`. I have checked the paths, and it is certainly not the issue of path. Does anyone know how to fix this? I tried looking up online, but there is really limited resources on this package.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: `pip install futures`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import name for the [`futures`](https://pypi.org/project/futures/) backport is the same as stdlib on Python 3.2+, i.e.

```
import concurrent.futures
```